# Using sed to remove words in a stopword list (Feeding sed a list of parameters to remove from a text file)

Tags: unix, sed, awk, grep

So, we all know that sed is great at finding and replacing all occurrences of words in a file:

```
sed -i 's/original_word/new_word/g' file.txt
```

But, can someone show me how to feed sed a list of 'original_words' from a file (similar to grep -f)? I just want to replace all with '' (erase them).

The original wordlist file is just a bunch of stopwords separated by line (wordlist.txt):

```
a
about
above
according
across
after
afterwards
```

This would be an easy way to take a list of stopwords and nuke them from a corpus (useful for cleaning data).

The file.txt looks like

```
05ricardo   RT @shakira: Immigration reform isn't about politics. It's about people mothers, kids. Obama is working for all of them. http://t.co/rAW ...    0
05ricardo   ?@ItsReginaG: Don't vote Obama. Because you will lose jobs, and die.? Lol   0
05ricardo   ?@shakira: Obama doubles Pell Grants - 700,000 more Latinos get help to go to college. Meet Johanny Adames http://t.co/EMg8NLGl Shak?. ?    -1
05rodriguez_a   My Comm teacher gave me a copy of Obama's speech that he gave the other night and I cried while reading it. It was that moving. -3
```

Comment: check this:http://theunixshell.blogspot.com/2013/01/perls-equivalent-of-grep-f.html

Answer (score 2):

You could also let sed write the sed-script for you (tested with GNU sed):

```
<stopwords sed 's:.*:s/\\b&\\b//:g' | sed -f - file.txt
```

Output:

```
05ricardo   RT @shakira: Immigration reform isn't  politics. It's about people mothers, kids. Obama is working for all of them. http://t.co/rAW ...    0
05ricardo   ?@ItsReginaG: Don't vote Obama. Because you will lose jobs, and die.? Lol   0
05ricardo   ?@shakira: Obama doubles Pell Grants - 700,000 more Latinos get help to go to college. Meet Johanny Adames http://t.co/EMg8NLGl Shak?. ?    -1
05rodriguez_a   My Comm teacher gave me  copy of Obama's speech that he gave the other night and I cried while reading it. It was that moving. -3
```

Comment: Note that Apple OS X sed does not support reading a script from standard input (`sed -f -`). So you'll have to write the command to a file first

Comment: @Otto: you are right, so this is a GNU sed only, unless a temporary script file is written. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Here's one way using `GNU sed`:

```
while IFS= read -r word; do sed -ri "s/( |)\b$word\b//g" file; done < wordlist
```

Contents of file:

```
how about I decide to look at it afterwards. What
across do you think? Is it a good idea to go out and about? I 
think I'd rather go up and above.
```

Results:

```
how I decide to look at it. What
 do you think? Is it good idea to go out and? I 
think I'd rather go up and.
```

Comment: Thanks for commenting! It doesn't like the -r for me:
sed: illegal option -- r

Comment: Yes unfortunately it looks like you're not using `GNU sed`. You're probably using `BSD sed` on OSX. If you drop the `-r` flag, you will need to remove the word boundaries (`\b`).

Comment: Indeed I am. Thank you. This is a good solution for anyone running GNU.

Comment: Invoking `sed` once per stop-word is grotesquely inefficient, especially if the list of stop words is large and the file is large.

Answer (score 1):

First, not all `sed` support `-i`, but it's not a necessary option as it is trivial to provide that functionality in a general way.  One simple option (assuming a non-csh family shell):

```
inline() { f=$1; shift; "$@" < $f > $f.out && mv $f.out $f; }
```

Then, to do the replacements (you haven't specified how you want to deal with word delimiters, so if "foo" is in the blacklist "bar foo baz" will end up with two spaces between "bar" and "baz") it is pretty straightforward with either awk or perl:

```
awk 'NR==FNR{a[$0]; next} {for( i in a ) gsub( i, "" )} 1' original-words file.txt
perl -wne 'if( $ARGV = $ARGV[0] ){ chop; push @no, $_; next } 
    foreach $x( @no ) {s/$x//g } print ' original-words file.txt
```

If you are happy with the results, either use `-i` with `perl` (not all `sed` support `-i`, but all `perl` > 5.0) or you can modify the file with:

```
inline file.txt awk 'NR==FNR{a[$0]; next} 
    {for( i in a ) gsub( i, "" )} 1' original-words -
```

Either of these solutions will be substantially faster than invoking `sed` for every word in the blacklist.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps this

```sh
#!/bin/sh
while read k
do
  sed -i "s/$k//g" file.txt
done < dict.txt
```

Comment: sed: 1: "file.txt": invalid command code S. Not sure if it likes the $k.

Comment: Sorry. I've added it.

Answer (score -1):

```
cat file.txt | grep  -vf wordlist.txt
```

Comment: That will delete lines containing any of the stop words, rather than just removing the stop words.

Comment: It will also match parts of words, so if `a` is a stopword there won't be much left...

Comment: I'm not sure but maybe `-x` can solve that.